# curl_json plugin not sending data (using it to send load balancer metrics)

Tags: rabbitmq, graphite, metric, collectd

I've implemented curl_jason plugin to recolect and send LoadBalancer metrics to my RabbitMQ to be graphed in Graphite.
Thing is, it's not sending any data, while it is working just fine (and great) with other plugins like memory, cpu, df root, network, etc. I've tried to troubleshoot following this suggestion: https://serverfault.com/questions/499378/collectd-stores-nan-instead-of-correct-value-in-ubuntu-12-04, but there're no issues coming out.

Here's my collectd.conf: https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8732467

Here're the last lines of collectd.log when I start it: https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8732488

The request is made against Rackspace API where my LoadBalancer is located, and if run manually, the curl gets me a json response perfectly normal.

Here's a snippet of it: https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8732518

Finally, collectd does not create any new folders besides network, df, memory, cpu, etc (all plugins that are correctly working and sending data) when started.

Hope this info helps and any comment will be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collectd's curl\_json plugin not sending data to graphite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853369/collectds-curl-json-plugin-not-sending-data-to-graphite)

Answer (score 0):

No answers..tried with collectd mail list and IRC. Closing.